# regarding the output of window(),partitionBy().orderby() in PySpark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I was running a set of program

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkByExamples.com').getOrCreate()
list=[['f1','a','b','c',1],
     ['f1','b','d','m',0],
     ['f2','a','b','c',0],
     ['f2','b','d','m',0],
     ['f3','a','b','c',1],
     ['f3','b','d','m',1],
     ['f4','a','b','c',0],
      ['f4','b','d','m',0]]

df= spark.createDataFrame(list,['function_name','param1','param2','param3','result'])
df.show()
```

[image]

and then I run

```
w=Window().partitionBy("function_name").orderBy(F.col("param1"),F.col("param2"),F.col("param3"))
dftest = df.withColumn("result_list", F.collect_list("result").over(w))
dftest.show()
```

the result is shown as the following, my question is that why in the column of "function_name", "f2" is ordered at the first position; `f4` is ordered following `f2`; `f1` is ordered following `f4`, etc.

[image]

Comment: There are certain Operations in Spark, which do not remain the order of the original Dataframe, because the partitions are separated between workers and the results being collected again.. I would guess your Window function is doing that, although the data is small enough to fit on the driver.
Lucky for you, you can just order it afterwards by your column "function_name".